# PhpStorm: How to automatically download files that have been created on remote/mounted drive

Tags: linux, laravel, phpstorm, samba, opensuse

**The question:**

*Is there any possibility to "watch" specific folders on my workspace for new files and automatically download them to my local project folder?
I would prefer a solution using only PhpStorm, if that's possible, but I am also fine with a Linux one!*

**The situation:**

I work with PhpStorm 2016.1.1 for Windows 8.1 on several different projects. Some of these projects are developed using Laravel, a very nice PHP framework.

All of my projects are cloned to an Open SUSE workspace server in my LAN by Git.

I import every project by using the "Create Project from existing Files" functionality and choosing the option "Files are accessable via network share or mounted drive".

I created the mounted drive using Samba.

As long as I keep developing in PhpStorm, everything works like a charm. Saved files are uploaded to my workspace automatically so I can debug my PHP projects in the browser very easily.

**The problem:**

Laravel offers a very nice command line tool to use called "artisan". This tool can, amongst other functionality, create specific classes for your projects like events, jobs, migrations, seeds, and so on.
This files created on the command line are, of course, not visible to me in PhpStorm because they are not in my local project folder until I manually start downloading from my workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it will help you but there is a Ticket from PhpStorm for a similiar function: [WI-1284](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1284)

It is about 6 Years old so i don´t think that this is coming soon. Perhaps there is another solution for it.

This could help for synchronisation of a remote host: [configuring-synchronization-with-a-web-server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-synchronization-with-a-web-server.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did read these. I hoped to find a better approach for this problem, because I think, I cannot be the only one struggeling with this :S